# Not Able to Call Client-Side Method With Signal R in ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

For some reason I'm having trouble simply calling a client-side method with Signal-R from my ASP.NET MVC App and was wondering if someone can assist.

Here's what I have so far.  I have a Hub called "NotifyUser" with the following:

```
public class NotifyUser : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

On the client in a javascript file in Document.Ready() I have:

```
$(function () 
{
   var notifyUser = $.connection.notifyUser;

   notifyUser.client.addNewMessageToPage= function (name, message) 
   {
        var x = 5;
   };

   $.connection.hub.start();
})
```

and I'm trying to call the client method from a controller on the server like this:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotifyUser>();
hubContext.Clients.All.Send("George", "Hi");
```

When I set a breakpoint in the "addNewMessageToPage" function on the client it is never hit.  Can someone assist?  Thanks.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

When you want call a hub method from a controller it must declare as **static** method like below:

```
public class NotifyUser : Hub
{
    public static void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

this changing solve your problem but note that if you want call a hub method from client java script it must be **non-static** so you have to declare two methods: one static for controller calling and the other one non-static for java-script calling

Comment: Thank you Hasan.  I added "static" to the Send method as you suggested above.  I also changed the caller in the controller to look like this:  NotifyUser.Send("George", "Hi");  However, it still is not calling the client method addNewMessageToPage()

Comment: Your-welcome, is this problem for this client method and other client signalr methods work fine?
if none of them work fine check jquery and SignalR scripted referenced correctly:
`<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>`
`<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>`